# Move your table or move your tables. For plural

Tags: singular-vs-plural

When I'm in a class with my colleagues, I have noticed that some teachers say "move your tables"

and others say "move your table" without **s**.

all of them talk to us as a group, their talking is not for one student.

So which one is correct? I think without **s** as each one of us has one table in front of him/her, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: what do you guys move your tables for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the teacher says "move your table" one can think of it as being addressed to each member of the group, indeed as shorthand for "Each of you move your table". Saying "move your tables" is addressed to the group collectively.

In this case there is no significant difference of meaning.